# How to make a checkbox part of the list item of a jquery-mobile split-con list

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a List that has a checkbox and an icon, so I decided to use a Split button List. Now I have 2 issues with the List:

1. The Checkbox appears in a box within the list item, I want it to be "flat", i.e. NO box around
2. The click causes the entire box to become blue, I want only the checkbox to get ticked

Can you help me with that?

I posted some example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/JY6EV/2/

//edit 2012/06/14
It seems that having a checbox on a listitem alway nests a button. As a workaroud I could add an icon (data-icon="check") but this does not work either.. any suggestions?

PS: I want to mimic the gmail list on iPad/iPhone:
[image: Google Mails List on iOS]
with my (faked) jquery mobile list:[image: jquery mimic of gmail]

What I tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/JY6EV/8/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I recently had to do the same. 
Since the solution of the second image is not present, I made it myself.

The list items:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="custom">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" />
        <label for="cb1">checkbox 1</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>
```

The css:

```
.custom {
     padding: 0;
}

.custom > div {
    margin: 0;
}

.custom > div > label {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/JY6EV/10/

Using the Gris layout for positioning but you will still need to tweak the look and feel

Comment: Could you explain a little more as to what it is you want?

Comment: Using a grid is basicaly a good idea, but I am losing split buttons and click/touch handling on the middle element. Seems to be a tough not only for me problem ;)

Comment: you would add you own button in the third grid